# Problems with the order of iframe creation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iframe

We started recently to modernize our old 1.0 web application.
Because the application is quite large, we change it step by step.
The first step was changing the landing page and login.
We also switched from 3 frames (top, menu on the left, main area) to 3 iframes.

In the new setting we create the 3 iframes dynamically: $("<iframe />").

Throughout the application we reference a frame by the number and not by the name/id. So the order of creation is very important. We cannot change this (into name/id) because it would be too time-consuming.

Approximately 1 of 200 users has problems with the order of creation of the iframes. Somehow the iframe of the first create command is in "parent.frames[1]" and the second one in "parent.frames[0]". This mixes up the whole application. It seems that in this case the 2nd command "overtakes" the first command.

When those very few users experience this problem, it occurs not only on a certain browser, but on all on this machine.

Is somebody out there who has had this or a similar situation with a web app and
found an explanation for the cause of this matter.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Make sure when the insert method runs, that the second iframe doesn't not get injected before the first, i.e. if `insertBefore` is being used. If it does then you get this issue. Do you know what browser that "1 of 200 user" use?

Comment: A user who had the problem on friday used an uptodate firefox, but it also happened on IE 11 on the same machine. So it maybe has to do with the graphics card or processor.

Comment: Is there anything within each iframe content that reveals which one it supposed to be? Can you, instead of checking the index, ask the iframe where it's positioned before you assign a src value to it?

Comment: Show us some code would of course be very good.

Comment: I could change from numbers to id/name in order to access it. But these commands/references are scattered over the hole application and to change it would be pretty time-consuming.

Comment: If those commands/references doesn't do any validation prior to execution, you likely would want to change that even if it is scattered all over. I suggest you call a function with a parameter, where you both validate and execute based on the param and target ... this way you open up for future flexibility, maybe using AJAX instead of iframe's etc., hard work though but maybe worth it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, LGSon.